# How to dynamically add macro variables in android.bp

Tags: android, go

How do I add condition in Android.bp. I want to add a cflags in the golang

```
bootstrap_go_package {
    name: "soong-AAA",
    pkgPath: "android/soong/AAA",
    deps: [
        "blueprint",
        "blueprint-pathtools",
        "soong",
        "soong-android",
        "soong-cc",
        "soong-genrule",
    ],
    srcs: [
        "AAA.go",
    ],
    pluginFor: ["soong_build"],
}

cc_library_static {
    name: "AAAi",
    defaults: [],
    include_dirs: [],
    srcs: [
       "AAA"
    ],
    shared_libs: [
       "AAA"
    ],
    whole_static_libs: [
       "AAA"
    ],
    header_libs: [
       "AAA"
    ],
    cflags: [
       "AAA"
    ],
 
}
```

I did it according to google's example
How to use go language to add macro variables to cflags
I wrote go, but it doesn't compile:

```
package AAA
 
import (
        "android/soong/android"
        "android/soong/cc"
        "fmt"
        "sync"
        "strings"
        "github.com/google/blueprint/proptools"
        "android/soong/apex"
        "android/soong/cc/config"
)
 
func init() {
        android.RegisterModuleType("cc_library_static", AdvAduioFeature_Cflag)
}
 
func AdvAduioFeature_Cflag() (android.Module) {
        module := cc.LibraryStaticFactory()
        android.AddLoadHook(module, AdvAduioFeature_Defaults)
        return module
}
 
func AdvAduioFeature_Defaults(ctx android.LoadHookContext) {
        type props struct {
                Include_dirs []string
                Srcs []string
                Shared_libs []stirng
                Whole_static_libs []string
                Header_libs []string
                Cflags []string
        }
        p := &props{}
 
        p.Cflags = append(p.Cflags, "-DAAAA")
        ctx.AppendProperties(p)
}
```

FAILED: out/host/linux-x86/bin/go/soong-btif/pkg/android/soong/btif.a
The above is the result of not compiling

Answer (score 0):

Just use soong_config_module_type in Android.bp, not need to add go file.

For example, an Android.bp file could have:

```
    soong_config_module_type {
        name: "acme_cc_defaults",
        module_type: "cc_defaults",
        config_namespace: "acme",
        variables: ["board"],
        bool_variables: ["feature"],
        value_variables: ["width"],
        properties: ["cflags", "srcs"],
    }

    soong_config_string_variable {
        name: "board",
        values: ["soc_a", "soc_b"],
    }

    acme_cc_defaults {
        name: "acme_defaults",
        cflags: ["-DGENERIC"],
        soong_config_variables: {
            board: {
                soc_a: {
                    cflags: ["-DSOC_A"],
                },
                soc_b: {
                    cflags: ["-DSOC_B"],
                },
                conditions_default: {
                    cflags: ["-DSOC_DEFAULT"],
                },
            },
            feature: {
                cflags: ["-DFEATURE"],
                conditions_default: {
                    cflags: ["-DFEATURE_DEFAULT"],
                },
            },
            width: {
                   cflags: ["-DWIDTH=%s"],
                conditions_default: {
                    cflags: ["-DWIDTH=DEFAULT"],
                },
            },
        },
    }

    cc_library {
        name: "libacme_foo",
        defaults: ["acme_defaults"],
        srcs: ["*.cpp"],
    }
```

The handle BoardConfig.mk file contained:

```
SOONG_CONFIG_NAMESPACES += acme
SOONG_CONFIG_acme += \
    board \
    feature \

SOONG_CONFIG_acme_board := soc_a
SOONG_CONFIG_acme_feature := true
SOONG_CONFIG_acme_width := 200
```

Finally have a fun.